# How do you include a mixin when using Minitest specs?

Tags: ruby, minitest

How should I include a mixin when using Minitest Specs?

This is an example of test suite in Minitest Specs:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

describe Meme do
  before do
    @meme = Meme.new
  end

  describe "when asked about cheeseburgers" do
    it "must respond positively" do
      @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?.must_equal "OHAI!"
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you want to include a mixin into `Meme` or is `Meme` your mixin or is the mixin unrelated to the object under test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top-level `describe` block defines a test case in essentially the same way as a class definition would if you were writing assert-style tests, so you'll just include your mixin module as you normally would:

```
require "minitest/autorun"

describe Meme do
  include MyMixin

  before do
    @meme = Meme.new
  end

  describe "when asked about cheeseburgers" do
    it "must respond positively" do
      @meme.i_can_has_cheezburger?.must_equal "OHAI!"
   end
  end
end
```

Remember: Minitest is just Ruby.